# RSS feed for responses

Tags: support

In other stackexchange sites like biology, there is an RSS feed for responses to my posts (e.g., [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/4936/responses)). No similar syntax seems to work for academia - is there a feed URL that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

RSS feeds do work on Academia.SE. For instance, [here's mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/53/).

The issue is that even though your user name is user4936, your actual user ID on *this* board is [9530](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9530/user4936)—check out the URL. So, if I use that ID, I [get a feed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/9530/).